# Combining two sheets and adding a new column with name associated to each range selected.

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have Sheet1 and Sheet2, each one have some data inside, let say from `A1:A3`. The dataset are like this

Sheet1:

```
col1
foo
bar
foobar
```

Sheet2:

```
col1
bat
man
batman
```

so I'm using the following formula to combine them :

`=query({ Sheet1!A1:A3;Sheet2!A1:A3 } ," select * where Col1 <> '' " ,1)`

however what I would like to do is associating in a new column a specific name for each date range. So I want something like this :

```
dataset1,foo
dateset1,bar
dataset1,foobar
dataset2,bat
dataset2,man
dataset2,batman
```

For specific reason I need this to happen in the formula. I cant just add another column in sheet1 and sheet2.

How do I do this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to add extra column to a table on the fly, before querying:

```
=query(arrayformula({iferror(Sheet1!A1:A/0, "dataset1"), Sheet1!A1:A; 
                     iferror(Sheet2!A1:A/0, "dataset2"), Sheet2!A1:A}), 
                     "select * where Col2 <> ''")
```

The effect of `iferror(Sheet1!A1:A/0, "dataset1")` is to create an array of the same size as `Sheet1!A1:A` filled with the string "dataset1".